# I need a class to call a class containing it as a property for a number of scenarios - how should this be implemented?

Tags: ruby, delegates, structure

I'm fairly new to Ruby, coming from Objective-C and Swift.

I've hit upon a problem where I have an object containing another object as a property. The second object has a `beginStream` function, by which it streams data from a server, and when it gets new data then it yields, thus the first object can respond. It looks like this:

```
class StreamManager
    def initialize
        @streams = Array.new
    end

    def setup_user_stream(user_id)
        stream = Stream.new(user_id)
        @streams << stream

        stream.begin_stream do |message|
            puts "A message was received: #{message}"
        end
    end
end

class Stream
    def initialize(user_id)
        @user_id = user_id
    end

    def begin_stream
        Thread.new do
            # Begins stream
            @client = Stream::Client.new(user_id)

            @client.on_error do
                # need to let StreamManager know about this
            end

            @client.on_message do |message|
                yield message if block_given?
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now I have this `on_error` call that I'm getting from my stream client, and I need to let my StreamManager know about it. How would I go about doing this?

In Objective-C/Swift, I'd have a protocol called StreamDelegate, which the stream would have as a weak property, and then the StreamManager would set the Stream's delegate to be itself, and respond to the functions provided in the protocol. So then the Stream would call the delegate function `@delegate?.streamDidReceiveError`, and the stream manager would be set as the `delegate`, and have that function implemented, and it'd be called.

I've simplified this example - the Stream is an abstraction over the Stream::Client, which is from another library and also gives out a bunch of other messages. But now I'm writing this, I'm thinking perhaps their way of having those different blocks I'm yielding is the way to go. In which case, I'd need to understand how to implement that myself? Or perhaps that would be a poor way to design my class - I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different approaches here:

1) You could still use the delegate pattern you're used to in Cocoa. The only difference is you wouldn't have a formal protocol/interface for it. Your Stream would take a delegate/callback handler object which is any object that implements certain methods. You can make those methods optional by checking the object responds to them before calling them. Your StreamManager could implement this interface and pass itself in to the stream as a dependency.

2) You could define callbacks on your Stream class for errors and messages rather than passing a single block to the begin_stream method.

3) Keep your existing API by instead of yielding the message, encapsulate the message or error in a Result object and yield that instead. I think this might be my preferred option.

Sorry for the lack of code examples but I'm writing this on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The parent `StreamManager` can pass itself as a variable to the child `Stream`.

```
def initialize(stream_manager, user_id)
    @stream_manager = stream_manager
    @user_id = user_id
end
```

And the initializing it, in setup_user_stream:

```
stream = Stream.new(self, user_id)
```

If you want slightly more verbose code, you can use named keywords:

```
def initialize(:stream_manager, :user_id)
```

then:

```
Stream.new(stream_manager: self, user_id: user_id)
```

Comment: Couple of questions... Wouldn't that make the stream manager a strongly-held property of the stream? Is there a way that I can have the stream manager be not necessarily of the StreamManager class, but just a class that conforms to a protocol? Would that be appropriate? Or is that still not really a Ruby thing?

Comment: Of course, you can write a wrapper class for the manager and reference that instead. I wouldn't think of it in terms of "is it a ruby thing", because it really depends on what kind of standards you're holding yourself to in terms of design patterns. If the manager class is abstract and you want to write some use-case specific code, by all means that's great, make a wrapper. But in a general sense, I don't see where the boogeyman is if store a reference to a separate class' instance.